# Rails params not being constructed correctly

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a strange issue.

I have tried a lot of different things to reproduce the issue but it has not been possible. The error shows up thanks to exception_notification.

I am sending a NSDictionary to the backend, and instead of being parsed as a dictionary, this is what I get (on the rails side):

```
   * Parameters : {"{\"facebook_id\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"account_type\":\"email\",\"poll_reminder\":\"0\",\"last_name\":\"\",\"picture_url\":\"\",\"email\":\"\",
\"birthday\":\"\",\"users_value_categories_attributes\":"=>{"{\"value_category_id\":25},{\"value_category_id\":24},
{\"value_category_id\":21},{\"value_id\":24,\"priority\":14},{\"value_id\":21,\"priority\":15},
{\"value_id\":58,\"priority\":16},
{\"value_id\":8,\"priority\":17},{\"value_id\":9,\"priority\":18},{\"value_id\":41,\"priority\":19},
{\"value_id\":27,\"priority\":20}"=>{",\"first_name\":\"\"}"
=>nil}}}}}
```

It is dictionary where the only key is my serialized dictionary!

This is the error on the rails side:

```
An ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError occurred in #:

  unknown attribute: {"facebook_id":"","city":"","account_type":"email","poll_reminder":"0","last_name":"","picture_url":"","email":"","birthday":"",":...........
  app/api/v2/resources/example_business_api.rb:6:in `block in <class:ExampleBusinessApi>'
```

params hash is like:

```
{"<MY SERIALIZED DICTIONARY" => nil }
```

instead of being the dictionary itself.

The relevant code in iOS is:

```
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[self getHTTPBodyForUser:theUser]];
```

getHTTPBodyForUser is the following:

```
+ (NSData *)getHTTPBodyForUser:(User *)user {
    // Load a tmp dictionary using user variable
     .... 
    // The tmp dictionary is totally fine
    NSError *error;
    NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];
    return postdata;
}
```

The weird part is that just some users are having the error.....

Any help?

Comment: Although you're apparently sending your JSON to a Rails app, this is not a Rails question, I removed that tag.

Comment: smathy I don't agree. It is related to how Rails parses the request and constructs the params object.

Comment: Since it is related to Rails, where is the code?

Comment: There's no need to show. The error description from exception_notifier clearly shows that the params hash is not well constructed, hence the rails code fails at the first attempt of accessing anything in the params